# Filtering 2 tables in R, based on selected choices and displaying graph in a shinny app

Tags: r, shiny, reticulate

I am new to r and shinny, and can't figure out how to fix my code. I have 2 dfs (df and historical), and I filter the df to display results selected from SelectInput (col, and col2, "Market" and "Month"). At the same time, I want to filter historical by the same values choosen for "Market" and "Month", and display below the table, a histogram of the filtered price_vector - that is, "average_price" from "historical" but filtered by chosen "Market" and "Month".

[image]

Any feedback is appreciated, and by the way, if you have a solution that uses reticulate, I dont mind it (no problem for me filtering a df using python/pandas, but I am teaching myself shinny and can't figure this out)

```
library(shiny)
library(reticulate)

df <- read.csv(file = 'scores.csv')
historical <- read.csv('TRAIN.csv')
price_vector <- historical$average_price

lmkt <- unique(df$market)
mth <- unique(df$month)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('col','Market',lmkt),
  selectInput('col2','Month',mth),
  dataTableOutput('table')
)

server <- function(input,output)

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
  df <- df
  {
    df = df[df[["market"]] == input$col,]
    df = df[df[["month"]] == input$col2,] 
    }
})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should post some sample data (even dummy) from both df and historical using `dput` so that someone can help you.  Add the data into the question.

Comment: Thank you. Will try to figure something out. Good feedback.

Comment: @YBS I uploaded some sample files to one of my github repos, with made up data. https://github.com/lmsanch/pyABS. Names are the same as the one in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two statements into one using `&` operator.

```
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lmsanch/pyABS/master/scores.csv')
historical <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lmsanch/pyABS/master/TRAIN.csv')
price_vector <- historical$average_price

lmkt <- unique(df$market)
mth <- unique(df$month)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('col','Market',lmkt),
  selectInput('col2','Month',mth),
  dataTableOutput('table'), 
  plotOutput('plot')
)

server <- function(input,output) {
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    df[df$market == input$col & df$month == input$col2, ]
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(price_vector[df$market == input$col & df$month == input$col2])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ronak, that makes the code cleaner. But how do I filter "historical" by the same parameters and display price_vector 's histogram?

Comment: How about the updated answer ? @LuisMiguel

Comment: Thank you. It did not work, R studio outputs the code in the console, does not render the chart. Now, if think that the last part would not work. In pandas (python_ the filter would be price_vector = historical[(historical["market"] == col) and (historical["month"]==col2)]["average_price"]. That's the one I need to plot. I think your filter for the chart would not work because the shapes/indices are different for both dfs...Nevertheless, I think I am getting to the right path, I'll give you credit for that :-)

Comment: For clarification, it does not render the chart either. I uploaded some sample files for this problem in one of my github repos github.com/lmsanch/pyABS. Names are the same as the one in the question

Comment: @LuisMiguel I am not sure why it doesn't work for you. I just used your data with the same code and it works for me. I have updated the answer to show the same.

Comment: It works now, somehow (I copied and pasted your solution). In any case, looks great! (by any chance, do you know how to customize the title of the chart? just point me in the right direction). Cheers

Comment: Sure, `?hist` has all the details. `main` would change the title of the plot. `xlab` and `ylab` to change x and y-axis labels. Example - `hist(price_vector[df$market == input$col & df$month == input$col2], main = 'New title', xlab = 'X-axis', ylab = 'Y-axis')`

Comment: Great! I am starting to like R Shinny better than Plotly for quick prototyping. Cheers!